# Loop through cells; Copy if not blank; Paste in sheet2 unformatted

Tags: excel, vba

I've been sitting with this problem for a few hours and would be very thankful if anyone here could assist me.

What I want to do:

1. For all cells A10:A180 in sheet1
2. If cell contains a date on the form YYYY-MM-DD
3. Copy cell and the two next cells to the right (e.g. A11:A13)
4. Remove all formatting, so as to only copy the value/string of the cell.
5. Paste at end of column in sheet2
6. When finished, sort the entries (whole row) by date

Any thoughts?

Best regards
Dean

---

**Edit**: copy&pasted code from comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear 
    Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range 
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet 
    Set wsFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1") 
    Set wsTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2") 
    Set R1 = wsFrom.Range("A:B") 
    Set R2 = wsTo.Range("A:B") 
    R1.Copy R2 
End Sub
```

Comment: what have you tried? and do you want to copy the date value as a plain number `42005`, the value formatted as a date `2015-01-01` or to convert it to a string `"2015-01-01"` and change the number format in output range as `text`?

Comment: I want the value formatted as date, so I can sort it by date in sheet2.

This is the basic outline of what I've tried, but it doesn't at all follow my algorithm above. I'm very new to VBA.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()  
   Sheet2.Cells.Clear  
   Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range  
   Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet  
   Set wsFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")  
   Set wsTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2")  
   Set R1 = wsFrom.Range("A:B")  
   Set R2 = wsTo.Range("A:B")  
   R1.Copy R2   

End Sub`

Comment: please edit your own question for pasting code, I copy&pasted your code for now, so you can see how to make code formatting

Comment: by 2 cells to the right, instead of `A11:A13` do you mean `A10:C10`?

Comment: also what do you mean by the `end of column in sheet2` please? value from cell A10 should be pasted where for example?

Comment: Oh, there are indeed some inaccuracies in my first post:

-Instead of A11:A13 I do mean A11:C11
-End of column in sheet2 is: say if the block A1:C5 contains values(i.e. five different entries with three columns with information per entry) then the content of the cells should be copied to the row following that: so the next entry will be pasted to row 6, the next after that to row 7, etc.

Sorry for that, I hope this resolves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some unclear points in your question, but following code should get you started how to properly load, manipulate and paste values between ranges using VBA arrays:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_nonblank()
    Dim data() As Variant  ' () creates an array instead of a simple variable
    Dim row_count, col_count, r, c, shift As Integer

    'load data from specified range into an array
    data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Range("A10:C180").Value2

    ' iterate through rows and shift data up to fill-in empty rows
    row_count = UBound(data, 1)
    col_count = UBound(data, 2)
    shift = 0
    For r = 1 To row_count
        If IsEmpty(data(r, 1)) Then
            shift = shift + 1
        ElseIf shift > 0 Then
            For c = 1 To col_count
                data(r - shift, c) = data(r, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r

    ' delete values, but not formatting
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2").Cells.ClearContents

    ' paste special as values, but only the shifted non-empty rows
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2").Range("A10") _
        .Resize(r - shift - 1, col_count) _
        .Value2 = data
End Sub
```

You will need to specify the formatting on the output sheet manually, but only once.